# Why the tab is not working in blade file in laravel?

Tags: html, laravel

I am new to laravel.

I need to fetch the data from the table and pass it to the blade file.

The problem is, `the tab is not working for the particular href`.

```
<div class="card">
    @foreach ($sample as $details)
       <div class = "card-header">
           <ul class="nav">
               <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-item" href="#{{ $details['id']}}_pane1"  data-toggle="tab"> Data1</a>
                </li>
                 <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-item" href="#{{ $details['id'] }}_pane2" data-toggle="tab">Data2</a>
                 </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
         <div class ="tab-content">
            <center class="tab-pane" id="{{ $details['id'] }}_pane1" role="tabpanel"> Content1</center>
            <center class="tab-pane" id="{{ $details['id'] }}_pane2" role="tabpanel"> Content2</center>
         </div>
   @endforeach
 </div>
```

**The tab is not working..**

This is how we pass the **table attribute to the href**?

Could someone please help?

Many thanks.

Comment: did you add class `show active` to the tab for display?

Comment: see what is result in the inspect element. and if you cant understand. let us to see.

Comment: @AmirKhaledian, the result in the inspect element is  <center class="tab-pane" id="1_pane1" role="tabpanel"> Content1</center> .. It took the Id: 1 from the table. But not sure, why it is not working.

Comment: all of code about this part in inspect please